# Every year last four months color different from other months in php

Tags: php, mysql, function, date, if-statement

I have calculate the employee experience(months) in joining date to current date. I         `want every **last four months in a year** (eg 9-12 and 21-24 and 33-36 etc....) employee`experience have shown as **different color**.(php code)

```
First year calculation has no problem after the years the conditions is not satisfy the `above criteria.`
This is my code but i need satisfy above criteria.

if($months % 9 == 0 || $months % 10 == 0 || $months % 11 == 0 || $months % 12 == 0)
  { 
  <span style="color:green;"><?php echo $u_tot_exp;?><span>
  }
  else
  { 
  <span style="color:black;"><?php echo $u_tot_exp;?><span>
  }
```

Comment: what is the problem / what is not working?

Comment: where is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your misunderstanding of the modulus operator `%`. You're using `$months % 11 == 0` to mean "if the month is the eleventh in a year", but that isn't what it means. It actually means "if the month is a multiple of eleven after the first month". So this means November one year (the eleventh month), then October the next (the 22nd) then September (the 33rd).

The effect multiplies with `% 10` or `% 9`. If we assume that the first year is 2014, it will select the following months:

```
2014: September, October, November, December
2015: June, August, October, December
2016: March, June, September, December
```

The `%` operator works by calculating the remainder when the number on the left is divided by the number on the right. Since we're working in years, we *always* need to divide by 12. You then want to check if the number left over is between `3` (i.e. September) and `0` (i.e. December).

```
$monthsToGo = $months % 12; // months remaining in the year
if ($monthsToGo >= 3) { // i.e. after September
    echo "<span style=\"color:green;\">$u_tot_exp<span>";
} else {
    echo "<span style=\"color:black;\">$u_tot_exp<span>";
}
```

Note that I have also fixed the code that outputs your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Finally i have get the result using this code.**   

 <?php 
$currentDate = date("d-m-Y");
    // joining_date is name of field in DB. 
    $date1 = date_create("".$u_joining_date.""); // 
    $date2 = date_create("".$currentDate."");
    $diff12 = date_diff($date2, $date1);
    $hub_days = $diff12->days;
    $months = $diff12->m;
    $years = $diff12->y;
    $tot_months = (($years * 12) + $months);
    //$monthsToGo = $months % 12;
    // months remaining in the year
    //$monthsmod = $monthsToGo % 10;
if ($tot_months != 0)
{
if($months % 9 == 0 || $months % 10 == 0 || $months % 11 == 0 || $months % 12 == 0)
{ 
?> 
<span style="color:green;"><?php echo $tot_months;?>month(s)<span>
<?php
}
else
{ 
?>
<span style="color:black;"><?php echo $tot_months;?>month(s)<span>
<?php 
}
}
?>
```